# Do I have to explicitly sanitize input fields in Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, sanitization

Do I need to explicitly sanitize all inputs, or does Angular already do it for me?

I have a login form - when submitted it sends it's data to the server. Does the data require explicit sanitization, or Angular automatically sanitize all input fields?

Comment: What do you mean by `the data entered gets evaluated for user` ? Is it redisplayed somewhere in the application ? Or do you ask if it will be sanitized before being sent to your server ?

Comment: read this: https://angular.io/guide/security

Comment: Also, [this might answer your question](https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-example)

Comment: If it will be sanitized before being sent to the server

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I appreciate your questions, it may be useful to others. Under no circumstances should the backed ever trust the front end, no framework, no custom library, **nothing**. If someone can exploit, inject, or otherwise harass your backed, they will, period. They will do so **bypassing** any front end framework or library and make **direct requests** to the endpoint, masquerading as anything necessary to do so.

And as @etarhan said, read this: https://angular.io/guide/security

Comment: Thank you! Quick follow up, if I had data coming in from the server and to the DOM, that would require sanitization, yes?

Comment: You should assume all data coming into the back end is corrupt or malformed and take necessary action to clean it up, make sure it is valid, etc. You are never in control of what is being sent to the server as you do not know where it is coming from.  The data you send back from YOUR API to the browser should be trusted as it is your data you have stored. Providing this data is not malformed in some way, you should be able to send it back to the client, as you are in control.

Answer (score 0):

No. If it's on the frontend then the user can change it in their browser, edit requests inflight and so on. Your sanitisation should be handled in the backend where the user cannot manipulate it.

I would also strongly recommend finding a framework for your backend language rather than reinventing the wheel.